# for loop stops outputting after 83 in JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp, jstl

I am trying to output the contents of an ArrayList in JSP. Funny thing is, it stops outputting after index 83. The size of the ArrayList is 2000. I stumbled upon the problem because I had tried this first in my javascript function:

```
 document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = '<%
 for(ClassInfo classes: classList)
 {
   out.print(classes.toString());
 }

 %>';
```

And nothing. So I tested it with something like this:

```
 document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = '<%
 for(int count = 0; count < classList.size(); count++)
 {
   out.print(classList.get(count).toString());
 }

 %>';
```

And still nothing. So I tweaked it just to see if I could get anything at all:

```
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = '<%
 for(int count = 0; count < 83; count++)
 {
   out.print(classList.get(count).toString());
 }

 %>';
```

And it works just fine, but not after 83. (i.e. if I change it to 84, nothing) Care to shed some light? This is my first day with JSP, and it seems a lot of people use JSTL for this type of thing, which from what I understand isn't packed in with Tomcat v7.

Comment: I would tweak some to make sure it is not logic issue, just print count and change loop to 85. out.print(count);

Comment: See what `out.print(classList.size())` prints.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad it prints out 2000.

Comment: @J-MANMORGAN Then check `out.print(classList.get(83))` if it prints `null` or not.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: If 83 null, it would endup NPE right?

Comment: @Nambari Yes, that's what I meant. I am not sure what would happen if a runtime exception is thrown within a JSP page.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad Nothing happens if I do that.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: If it is runtime/compile time exception, yes JSP throws that exception on page, unless there are catch blocks.

Comment: @Nambari  To thicken the plot, if I replace it with this "out.print("Test");" when using classList.size(), it works. It prints out "Test" 2000 times.

Comment: @J-MANMORGAN: That tells you have only 82 values in your arrayList and remaining element are empty Strings (not even nulls(. Just to prove point before printing, add may be something 101,102,103 etc., you will see them in out.print

Comment: @Nambari I don't believe this is the case because if I do out.print(classList.get(1992).toString()) it will print it out, if I understood you correctly.

Comment: How exactly are you observing "It stops outputting"? Did you look straight in the particular JavaScript code in the generated HTML output (rightclick page in browser, View Source) or did you observe that based on expected behaviour of the executed JavaScript code? (and thus you observed like as enduser instead of as developer) The cause may for instance have been just a singlequote in the printed value of the 84th item (causing a JS syntax error) and thus all of those items should be still visible in the generated HTML output.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try replacing

```
 document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = '<%
 for(ClassInfo classes: classList)
 {
   out.print(classes.toString());
 }
 %>';
```

with

```
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = '';
<% for (ClassInfo classes : classList)  { %>
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML += '<%= ""+classes %> ';
<% } %>
```

While this is highly inefficient (lots of reflow in the browser, lookup of test many times), it might help in debugging. My guess is (as mentioned in the comments) that elements in your ArrayList are null. In this setup (""+classes) the string "null" will be appended to the output.

Comment: This is the oddest thing I have ever dealt with. When I debug, it clearly shows that all of the contents in the arraylist have ClassInfo values. Thanks for all the suggestions, I will get back when I figure out the issue.

Comment: Is there any way the toString() method of ClassInfo might throw an Exception?